# Как на wordpress woocomerce добавить описание в товар?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Есть у меня проект на wordpress woocomerce. По умолчанию описание выводится только на полноценной странице с товаром. А я хочу добавить в выводимый товар описание (состав) среди перечня товаров:

[image: стейк]

не подскажите, как это можно сделать? 
Желательно, чтобы была возможность редактирования из админки.
Может в woocomerce уже есть для этого готовые решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать выводить краткое описание под товаром, надо добавить код в functions.php

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_add_short_description', 9 );
function my_add_short_description() {
   echo '<span class="title-description">' . the_excerpt() . '</span><br />';
}
```

Или вот еще попробуйте вывод краткого описания товара

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
```